# Equipartition theorem for the second moment of the energy

Tags: statistical-mechanics, ideal-gas, kinetic-theory

The [equipartition theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equipartition_theorem#Extreme_relativistic_ideal_gases) provides a convenient way to derive a relation between the hamiltonian of an ideal gas to the temperature of the system. For an extreme relativistic ideal gas, the kinetic energy of a single particle is given by the formula

$$H=c\sqrt{p_x^2+p_y^2+p_z^2}.$$

Then one can write the average

$$\langle H\rangle=\langle p_x\frac{\partial H}{\partial p_x}\rangle+\langle p_y\frac{\partial H}{\partial p_y}\rangle+\langle p_z\frac{\partial H}{\partial p_z}\rangle= 3 k_{\small\text{B}} T$$

where  the last equality follows from the equipartition formula.

Is it possible to get a similar relation for the second moment of the energy $\langle H^2\rangle$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to the formula
$$
\langle p_x \frac{\partial H}{\partial p_x} \rangle = k_BT,
$$
there exists the following relation
$$
\langle p_x \frac{\partial H^2}{\partial p_x} \rangle = 2 k_BT \langle H \rangle + 2(k_B T)^2. \quad (1)
$$
For the hamiltonian of an ultrarelativistic particle, we have
$$
H^2 = \frac12\left(p_x \frac{\partial H^2}{\partial p_x} + p_y \frac{\partial H^2}{\partial p_y} + p_z \frac{\partial H^2}{\partial p_z} \right)
$$
Together with $\langle H \rangle = 3k_BT$, this gives
$$
\langle H^2 \rangle = 12(k_BT)^2.
$$

Comment: Thank you. Do you have a reference where I can look up the second identity?

Comment: @kaffeeauf, I don't have a reference. I've derived it myself. Do you know how to derive a relation for $<p_x\partial H/\partial p_x>$? The same method gives a relation for $H^2$.

Comment: The formula (1) is general. It is applicable to any reasonable hamiltonian $H$.